# Cancelling a task that is non-responsive

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to cancel a task that is stuck on a class method from the `.Net framework`.

I have a project that scans a large amount of remote workstations on the network and perform various operations on each.  Each machine is its own async task, and each operation being performed within is it's own task that is waited on before going to the next.

Every now and then, maybe 1 in a few thousand machines, for unknown reasons (network connection?, workstation health issues?) a native `.Net function`, like `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey`, or `Enumerable.Count` will hang without throwing an exception.  In situations like this, I'd like to abort or cancel the task after x seconds, but since the code is essentially frozen, I don't think I can use a cancellation token for that.

The only solution I currently have been able to come up with is to use a `task.wait` for each operation with a timeout...which does work, except it leaves that thread out there still trying to execute.  It's not a true cancellation, it's just abandonment.

Is there an option that I'm missing where I can have `task.wait` type timeout functionality that actually kills the stuck task?

```
private static async Task scanRow(string machine)
{
    string result;
    Task task = null;

    foreach (var operationToRun in operations)
    {
        switch (operationToRun)
        {
            case "Operation1":
                result = await Operation1(machine);
                break;
            case "Operation2":
                task = Task.Run(() => { result = Operation2(machine); });
                if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
                {
                    //time out logic
                    //code continues but task is left in limbo
                }
                else
                {
                    //did not time out logic
                }
                break;
        }

        //do stuff with result
    }
}

public static Task<string> Operation1(string machine)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //.net method that hangs here
    }
}

public static Task<string> Operation2(string machine)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //.net method that hangs here
    }
}
```

`Operation1` has the potential to hang forever. `Operation2` will time out after 10 seconds...and the code will continue, but never cleans up the abandoned task.  I'm hoping for a third option.

Comment: There is no option to really cancel a task from outside. With a CancellationToken you can hand over a **request** for cancellation and the task should cancel because of that cancellation request. If the task did not support such a cancellation then it did not support cancellation

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was afraid that this was the answer, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking any other options.

Comment: As you probably know, this can be accomplished using timers and threads, but not currently with tasks.

Comment: I was so focused on tasks I hadn't considered using timers and threads.  I think that's going to solve my issue.  Thanks!